# Python Netmiko Connect to hosts from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, netmiko

I'm creating a dictionary from a CSV file where the hostnames are the keys and what I need is to get the keys from the dictionary and use them as the `host` to connect to and have the `device_type` be the `device_platform` item for that particular key.

The CSV file would look something like this:

```
hostnames,device_platform,device_role
co-agg-r1.nunya.com,cisco_ios,co-agg-r
co-edg-fw1.nunya.com,cisco_asa,co-edg-fw
co-acc-sw1.nunya.com,cisco_ios,co-acc-sw
co-acc-rsw1.nunya.com,broadcom_icos,co-acc-rsw
```

Dictionary would look like this slightly modified for readability:

```py
devices_dict = {
    'co-agg-r1.nunya.com': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-agg-r'},
    'co-edg-fw1.nunya.com': {'device_platform': 'cisco_asa', 'device_role': 'co-edg-fw'},
    'co-acc-sw1.nunya.com': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-acc-sw'},
    'co-acc-rsw1.nunya.com': {'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos', 'device_role': 'co-acc-rsw'}
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import csv
import getpass
import readline

username = input('Username: ')
pwd = getpass.getpass()

with open("devices.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    keys = next(reader)[1:]
    devices_dict = {key: dict(zip(keys, values)) for key, *values in reader}
```

I'd like to use something like this for the connection info for Netmiko ConnectHandler:

```py
connection_info = {
    'ip': host, # This would be the hostname/key
    'port': 22,
    'username': username.lower(),
    'password': pwd,
    'secret': pwd,
    'device_type': device_platform, # I need this to be the value of device_platform for the hostname that we're connecting to.
    'verbose': True,
    'fast_cli': False
}

ssh_connection = ConnectHandler(**connection_info)
```

What's the best way to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `connection_info` to look like this:

```
connection_info = {
  'port': 22,
  'username': username.lower(),
  'password': pwd,
  'secret': pwd,
  'verbose': True,
  'fast_cli': False
}
```

This leaves only the kv pairs that are the same for every session.  Then loop through your devices_dict:

```
for device, info in device_dict.items():
    platform = info['device_platform']
    ssh_connection = ConnectHandler(ip=device, device_type=platform, **connection_info)
    ssh_connection.send_command('whatever needs to be done')
```

This creates a session with the information unique to that particular device, and recycles the connection_info.